# Why's the ADT so unhappy about "installLocation"?

Tags: android, eclipse

So, Eclipse (the ADT) is throwing "no resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' android" in the Manifest.  It just magically started doing that overnight.  My app was fine when I closed it last night, but it started up with the error this morning.  My current minimum SDK is "8" and my target is "16".  From other posts with the same problem I found a few suggestions that worked for them, but failed for me.  I've tried removing the target, bumping my SDK up to 19, and removing installLocation.  Nothing seems to make any difference so far.  I've even gone so far as to make the changes and restart Eclipse each time.  Still no change.  I've run Google out of ideas now, looking for some fresh ideas to try!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: The whole ADT/Eclipse?

Comment: Give us your manifest and a copy of logcat error please

Comment: I reinstalled Eclipse, Git, and re-cloned the project.  Now I've got a new mystery as the installLocation error is gone, but it's spewing "The import java.util cannot be resolved" for a simple "import java.util.ArrayList;" that was fine before.  This is crazy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you put down reinstall as an answer, I'll accept it and move my answer into comments or edit it in.  That would make more sense than having yours as a comment and mine as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of our contractors once said "Cascading Waves of Failures".  I reinstalled Eclipse and was presented with "The import java.util cannot be resolved".  I flipped the SDK version down to 1.6 only and that error went away.  I was then presented with the original error again, as well as all references to "R" being broken.  I pulled the installLocation out of the XML (since it's not supported in API 4).  That solved both the XML issue this time (despite not working earlier today) and the "R" problem also went away.

Root cause, well, not completely sure, but a complete deletion and reinstall of Eclipse got the ball rolling again.  Before that, nothing I did seemed to actually have any impact.